# Open original pdf file and not download it

Tags: php, laravel, smb

I have a Laravel App that can upload file to a folder. 
The folder is a symlink to /media/folder_name, that is a mount point of a Windows share (mounted via fstab).
Upload and Download works.

The download action returns a copy of the file:

```
return response()->file($path_file);
```

I want that the download action to show me the original file (saved in windows folder, like: `//192.168.1.2/share/folder/file.pdf`).
It is possible?

Comment: So you mean you don’t want an actual download (triggered via server-side code that issues headers and then pipes through the file content) at all any more, but just _redirect_ the user to a URL of the form `//192.168.1.2/share/folder/file.pdf`? Well that would require that you store that URL somewhere to begin with - which of course doesn’t happen with a regular upload. (And with an HTTP upload you don’t _get_ the full original client side path any more these days - so you would have to supply that info in _addition_ to the upload somehow.)

Comment: Ok,  store the ip address of the server it's not a problem. `return redirect()->away('//192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf') ` doesn't works...

Comment: _“Doesn't work”_ doesn’t work as a problem description. So, what actually happens? Errors? Redirect happens, but the following request does not result in what you expected? (Is there even a web server running under that IP address, that could answer any such HTTP request?)

Comment: Ok. In the windows machine (192.168.1.2) there isn't a web server. If inside the Windows machina, with Firefox, I type `//192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf`, so Firefox open the file. If I type the same address with Firefox in my webserver (in the same lan, of course), Firefox can't find the file. The share has "Everyone" to read/write permission. Finally, my webserver can mount the share in /media/share and write inside it. Thanks

Comment: _“I type //192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf, so Firefox open the file”_ - still, that is not actually access via HTTP to begin with. (Probably gets prefixed with the pseudo-protocol `file:///` automatically in the address bar, I presume?) You can not redirect to such an address as you would with a normal HTTP URL - the browser is going to assume that this is a protocol-relative URL, and since you are _on_ a page accessed via HTTP when this happens, it will automatically add that prefix then, resulting in `http://192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf` - which isn’t accessible.

Comment: If anything, you would have to include the `file` protocol in your redirect already. (Not sure whether the Laravel function supports that though, you’d have to test it. Might be it sees that as a “faulty” URL and somehow tries to correct it itself.)

Comment: Even if I type `file://///192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf` , the result is `File not found`. The `file://` protocol is automatically added.

Comment: Maybe it could work if you “link” to the file URL, instead of trying to issue a redirect? (Meaning, respond with an HTML document instead, that either links to that address, or automatically “goes” there by assigning it to location.href)

Comment: It's not the same to write the address in firefox address bar?

Comment: Apparently not possible in Firefox, for security reasons: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work

Answer (score 0):

After some research, direct link to local resource is denied in Firefox and Chrome for security reasons.

So, the solution is to install the [Local Filesystem Links](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/) extension for firefox. In Laravel, return a blank page with the link to the resource, like: `file:////192.168.1.2/folder/file.pdf`.

Finally, when you click the pdf link, the original resource is opened with the default program (Adobe Reader, for example).